# "Error MT2002: Failed to resolve UIKit.UICollectionView::set_DataSource" after updating Xamarin.Forms iOS app to universal API

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I updated one of my sample Xamarin Forms applications to the new Universal API and Xamarin.Forms 1.3.0.6286-pre4.

The main parts of the two projects:

```
//App.cs in XamlMaps (the PCL part)
namespace XamlMap
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {   
            MainPage = new MainPage();    //Main page is a Xaml which holds a Label
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnResume");
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep");
            base.OnSleep();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnStart");
            base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}

//AppDelegate.cs in XamlMaps.iOS
namespace XamlMap.iOS
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Forms.Init();

            LoadApplication (new App ());

            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

I removed all other dependencies except for Xamarin.Forms.

I am still receving the following error when I am trying to build for the device:

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void UIKit.UICollectionView::set_DataSource(UIKit.UICollectionViewDataSource)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065" (MT2002) (XamlPlayer.iOS)

When I run my projects on the simulator everything works just fine: the apps come up and everything works as before.

Any idea why Mtouch is failing on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms 1.3.0 was based on a **preview** version of the **unified** API. There's been several previews since Xamarin.iOS 7.4 was released (last summer) and, as previews, there were some incompatible changes between the versions (that requires you to recompile any references).

The final/stable **unified** API that ships with Xamarin.iOS 8.6 has a few differences with the previews. You'll need an updated version of Xamarin.Forms (1.3.1 iirc) that was built against the final API.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a native libraries, you can set Options->iOS Build->Link behavior to Din't link.

Answer (score 0):

> The MT2002 error occurs because some symbol does not exists in the mscorlib.dll assembly. >Some code from your application (or 3rd party assemblies) is using this (missing) API and >needs to be removed/recompiled.

Try to set the linker to link all assemblies, last time I had the same problem with splat and it worked.